# Add element to list on update, together with other changes in a record

Tags: elm

I have the following `initialModel`,

```
initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { cards =
        [ { url = "Gita.jpg", card = 1, selected = False }
        , { url = "Kali.jpg", card = 2, selected = False }
        , { url = "Arjuna.jpg", card = 3, selected = False }
        , { url = "Krishna.jpg", card = 4, selected = False }
        , { url = "Manjusri.jpg", card = 5, selected = False }
        , { url = "siddartha.jpg", card = 6, selected = False }
        , { url = "bodhidharma2.jpg", card = 7, selected = False }
        ]
    , selectedCards = [ "card1" ]
    , activeCard = ""
    }
```

And I have them hooked with `onClick`,

```
type Msg
    = ClickedCard { url : String, id : String }
    | Other


update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of
        ClickedCard data ->
            { model
                | activeCard = data.id
                , selectedCards = selectedCards ++ data.id -- This line is pseudo-code
            }

        _ ->
            model
```

How can I make that update work? So, in the end, every click on a new card should make it on the `selectedCards` list.

Comment: https://elm-lang.org/docs/syntax#lists

Comment: Great, I tried this one too. But, `, selectedCards = selectedCards :: data.id` still doesn't work. Because, I can't reference selecedCards on he right side of the expression

Comment: You access record fields with `.`, so `model.selectedCards`. But you also have it the wrong way, it should be `data.id :: model.selectedCards`.

Comment: That did work - no errors. But, the application didn't work as expected - back to the drawing board. Thank you.